# apple scripting with Messages to take action on URL

Tags: applescript, message

I'm trying to write an AppleScript for Messages such that if I get a message that contains a URL, the script automatically opens the link in my browser.

I've been able to set a script to run that sends me a notification with the properties of the message, but I've not yet been able to figure out how to take action on the URL.

Here's what I've been able to produce:

```
using terms from application "Messages"
    on message received from theSender for theChat with theContents
      display notification theContents as text ¬
          with title "New Message from " & theSender
    end on message received
end using terms
```

Comment: the notification doesn't actually work as written, but I'm certain I can probably troubleshoot that.  It doesn't seem to be able to coerce theContents into type text.

Comment: Do you get an error when you run your script? If so, please add the exact text of the error to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that might help you:

```
set msg to theContents as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to space
set msg to msg as list
repeat with x in items of msg
    if "http" is in x then
        display dialog x
    end if
end repeat
```